# What does the formula of an Adjacency matrix of an undirected graph trasposed matrix equal?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be the adjacency matrix of an undirected network with n nodes and let 1 $\in R^n$ be a column vector whose elements are all 1. What does the formula $1^T \cdot A \cdot 1$ equal?

Two times the number of edges of a graph or 
The square of the number of nodes of a graph?

and why?

thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $1^T \cdot A \cdot 1$?

Comment: Have you played around with some toy examples, like $3\times 3$ or $4\times 4$?

Comment: Is this homework? Have you tried anything at all? I'm sure you can work it out if you actually try. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$1^T \cdot A \cdot 1$ is the sum of all the entries in the matrix $A$. These entries are, in position $ij$, 1 if there is an edge from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$, and 0 otherwise. (Or, in a multigraph, the number of edges from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.) Since your graph is undirected, each edge shows up twice: once in position $ij$ and once in position $ji$ (except for any loops, which just show up in position $ii$.)

So, adding all these up gives you twice the number of edges in the graph, at least if there are no loops.

(With loops, it is still true, if you adopt an appropriate convention, e.g. put a 1 in entry $ii$ and count loops as half an edge, or else put a 2 in entry $ii$ (because the loop is incident to vertex $i$ twice.))